# How to get ID of item from database in <select><option> Tag

Tags: php, html

Hello. I have a problem with the more difficult code but here I tried to simplify it a bit just to ask a question ... I have 3 tables in database: cars(cars_id,model), customers(customer_id,name,surname), sales(sales_id,customer_id,cars_id).And I don't know how to get the ID for the selected option in the select option tag. For example, for BMW X6 I want to get to ID = 2 and put this value in the cars_id column in the SALES table to avoid data redundancy. It's about relation. cars_id in the CARS table is the same as cars_id in the SALES table. But I want to do this using PHP MySQL.

```
<?php
//index.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=store", "root", "");
function fill_unit_select_box($connect)
{ 
 $output = '';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM cars";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option  value="'.$row["model"].'">'.$row["model"].'</option>';
 }

 return $output;
}

?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Sales form</title>
  <script src="jquery-3.5.0.min.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <h3 align="center">Sales form</h3><br />
   <form method="post" id="insert_form">
    <div class="table-repsonsive">
     <span id="error"></span>
     <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
    <tr>
        <th >sales</th>    
        <th >customer</th>
        <th >cars</th>
        <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Add</span></button></th>
    </tr>
     </table>
     <div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Send" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
    var html = '';
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td class="lp"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="customers_name[]"></td>';
    html += '<td><select style="backbround-color:white;"name="cars_name[]" class="form-control size_id"><option value=""><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></option></select></td>';
    html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">Usuń</span></button></td></tr>';
    $('#item_table').append(html);
    var count=0;
    $('.lp').each(function(){
      count=count+1;
      $(this).text(count);
  });
 });


 $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  if(error == '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data)
    {
     if(data == 'ok')
     {
      $('#item_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
      $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Dane zostały wysłane</div>');
     }
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {
   $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
  }
 });

});

</script>   




<?php
//insert.php;
session_start();

if(isset($_POST["customers_name"]))
{
 $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=store", "root", "");
 for($count = 0; $count < count($_POST["customers_name"]); $count++)
 {  
    $query = "INSERT INTO sales
    (customer_id,cars_id) 
    VALUES (:customer_id,:cars_id)
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
    array(
        ':customer_id'  => $_POST["customers_name"][$count],    
        ':cars_id'  => $_POST["cars_name"][$count],
   )
  );
 }
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 if(isset($result))
 {
  echo 'ok';
 }
}
?>
```

[image: To make it more clear]

Comment: then, why don't you use $row["id"] instead of $row["model"] in the value attribute?

Comment: `'<option  value="'.$row["cars_id"].'">'.$row["model"].'</option>'`

Answer (score -1):

So, you just have to edit your $output like this.
value="'.$row["model"] to value="'.$row["cars_id"]
change to cars_id only for value, so the user can see the name but you get id on form submit.

Comment: Yes I can change it to '<option value="'.$row["cars_id"].'">'.$row["model"].'</option>'  but later in insert.php I need to put it into line ->   :':cars_id'  => $_POST["    HERE      "][$count] and send it to database. Can I do this? How to put it instead of name attibute inside $_POST [  ]???

Comment: Because I need to send the cars_id to database in insert.php

Comment: The key of $_POST['key'] can be set through html name-attribute.
Also it is possible to change this key within ajax call.

Comment: So if you have something like this: 
<input name="mySpecialKey">
You can access this value after post-request with $_POST['mySpecialKey'].

Comment: Thats the thing I am asking for. I know I  can access this value after post-request with $_POST['mySpecialKey'] but I need send instead of name attr value=$row["cars_id"]. I need to send to database $row["cars_id"]. instead of name attr. because in select option we have name in select tag for eg <select name=" "></select> so it is easy to send name value form select tag but in <option> we have value attr instead of name

Comment: Okay, now I am getting it. The value of the select field will be the selected option field within the select field.
So you can access the value of the selected option field by name-attribute of select-tag.

Comment: We are close:) The name attribut of the select tag give me for example BMWX6 but does't give me the cars_id "2" but I need to send to database in case BMWX6 nr 2 that is cars_id. I know how to send model it is easy but the respective id its more difficult:(

Comment: Now you only have to change the value of the option tag to $row['cars_id'] so you get the value of the id instead of the name of the car.